# background color and centering my logo in the middle of my navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color

```html
<!---LOGO IN MIDDLE-->

  <style>
    body{
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }

    img{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      margin-top: 31px;
    }
  </style>
</body>
<body>
  <img src="./IMAGES/white logo.png" width="80" height="80" alt="logo">
</body>
</a>
</div>
```

I'm having problems putting background color and centering my logo in
the center of my navigation bar.

Comment: Wrap your image in a div and add display of flex and justify-content: center.

Comment: @dalelandry Can you show me how I can wrap the image? Like an example.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what are you looking for?

```css
body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-top: 31px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Hku.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="logo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made little changes on html :

```
<nav>
  <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png/google-logo-png-webinar-optimizing-for-success-google-business-webinar-13.png" alt="logo">
</nav>
```

CSS Code :

```
body{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

nav{
  /* Add Background color in Navigation Menu */
  background:black;
  height:10vh;

  /* Align logo in center */
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

I hope my solution will solved your problem.